# Adaptation of new keynesian model

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, price, new-keynesian-economics

I'm looking for literature in new keynesian model adaptation to model price shocks. I'm aware of Blanchard, Olivier, and Jordi Gali.  2007.  [“The Macroeconomic Effects of Oil Shocks: Why Are the 2000s So Different from 1970s.”](http://www.nber.org/papers/w13368.pdf)  NBER Working Paper No. 13368. Do you know other adaptations of the new keynesian model in this way or from the exporting country view?